# Why does function "click" memorize data from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am taking a course on javascript and the task was to get JSON data from JSONPLACEHOLDER and display users names. By clicking their names, full data about user should be displayed.

JS code:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector(".list-group");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");

function getUsers(renderUsers) {
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
   xhr.addEventListener("load", () => {
      const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      renderUsers(response);
   });

   xhr.addEventListener("error", () => {
      console.log("error");
   });

   xhr.send();
}

function renderUsers(response) {
   const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
   response.forEach((user) => {
      const li = document.createElement("li");
      li.classList.add("list-group-item");
      li.textContent = user.name;
      li.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
         h1.innerHTML = `<h3>Email: ${user.email} <br>
                          Username: ${user.username} <br></h3>
                          Address: <h5>${user.address["street"]}, ${user.address["city"]}, ${user.address["zipcode"]}</h5>
                          </h3>Phone: ${user.phone}
                          </h3>`;
      });
      fragment.appendChild(li);
   });
   ul.appendChild(fragment);
}

getUsers(renderUsers);
```

So, I dont know, why infornation is shown. After all, this is not saved anywhere or I don't understand something.
Please, tell me the logic where does the information come from by clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Function `getUsers` makes a request to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` and receives users JSON data in return. Then function `renderUsers` gets called, which loops over parsed JSON data and inserts/renders users with full data in html.

More info about XMLHttpRequests 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

First sample user info from the request made

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
```

About JSON 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: It means that when I add event listener on click, html memorize information and displays it when I click?

Comment: You add an event listener for click on your button. When button gets clicked getUsers method is called and the description I made above happens. Html doesn't "memorize" any information, it's just text that was generated  with your received data + exisitng html tags and can be then seen on your webpage.

Comment: I think you should start with the basics of html, css etc. before moving on to javascript & json.

Comment: I know css and html basics, but noone doesn't tell how it works. Of course I know that html is just text. But the teacher again accesses the json by url to pick up the information, respectively, I did not understand why my version worked for me.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You wanted to know the logic behind why the user information show up on button click and I described it.